# My TP-Link (TL-WA701ND) Bricked

Tags: dd-wrt, wireless-access-point, firmware, flashing

Welcome everyone, Today I was working to restore my access point TL-WA701ND to its original firmare from DD-WRT after taking the right steps my access point LEDs ar blinking (four LEDs at once except power) and after many googling I knew that the access point was bricked and I'm tired of trying solutions like resetting and using TFTP32 But no luck... NOTE: access point dont respond and cannot be opened using browser. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing very useful you can do if it is bricked.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen I heard about self recovery available in this model but I'm stuck in steps..

Comment: The user guide doesn't mention anything about "self recovery". Where did you find steps for that? What are the steps and which one causes you trouble? Only thing to do besides that is to reset the device to factory defaults from the reset button, but you probably did that already. Flashing the firmware otherwise requires special tools to do, I think. I wouldn't go there, it's not worth the effort.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen 
Yeah of course tried the reset button dozen times without any respond, and about the solutions I tried a lot of them LIKE:
https://forum.tp-link.com/showthread.php?75206-TL-WDR4300-inaccessible-all-leds-blink&p=152670&viewfull=1#post152670

Comment: That "solution" is for TL-WDR4300 model. How did you conclude that it works for your model, even though they are completely different devices? Also in that case the firmware was not updated.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen Yes I know that the model is different, but I saw a video about this solution for my model on  [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOiba-scdtk) but I'm stuck in it
If you can hear the video and help..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83160/discussion-between-ahmed-hassan-suror-and-aulis-ronkainen).

Answer (score 1):

You should have serial pin headers on your TL-WA701ND board. You could use them for a serial connection with your PC to restore the firmware on the router, given that the bootloader is not bricked. Use TFTP to transfer the firmware and flash it. This way you might be able to "unbrick" it. Honestly, it might be easier to buy a new router, sorry.

Comment: Can you help me more providing steps or photos?